# Jssor Slider... How to change Slider transitions?

Tags: slider, jssor

I included a responsive Jssor Slider in one page and it changes the slides using the default option. It drops out slide1 to the left, replacing it with the next slide that comes from right, and so on.

I want to change the slide transition effect to a simple FADE effect where Jssor fades out slide1 meanwhile it fades in the slide2 and so on....

I cant find the way to insert the code generated by the tool-slideshow-transition-builder....... but I can't understand how and where include it into the JS code.

The code generated by tool-slideshow-transition-builder is:

```
{$Duration:3000,$Opacity:2}
```

The current JS code for transitions is the following in my JS file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var _CaptionTransitions = [];
_CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 900, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
_CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
_CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 900, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
_CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 900, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $Jease$.$InOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
_CaptionTransitions["ZMF|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$OutQuad, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 };
_CaptionTransitions["RTT|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$OutQuad, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
_CaptionTransitions["RTT|2"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 3, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$InQuad, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} };
_CaptionTransitions["RTTL|BR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
_CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 15, $Easing: { $Clip: $Jease$.$InOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
_CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|L"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 1, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $Jease$.$InOutCubic} };
_CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|R"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 2, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $Jease$.$InOutCubic} };
_CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR-FADE"] = {$Duration:1200,$Clip:3,$Opacity:1.7,$During:{$Clip:[0.5,0.5],$Opacity:[0,0.5]}};

_CaptionTransitions["BL"] = {$Duration:900,x:0.6,y:-0.6,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutSine,$Top:$Jease$.$InOutSine},$Opacity:2};
_CaptionTransitions["ZM"] = {$Duration:900,$Zoom:1,$Easing:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:2};
_CaptionTransitions["ZMS|B"] = {$Duration:900,y:-0.6,$Zoom:1,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic},$Opacity:2};
_CaptionTransitions["ZMS|R"] = {$Duration:900,x:-0.6,$Zoom:1,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InCubic},$Opacity:2};
_CaptionTransitions["FADE"] = {$Duration:900,$Opacity:2};
_CaptionTransitions["FADE*JDN|L"] = {$Duration:1200,x:0.6,y:0.6,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$Linear,$Top:$Jease$.$OutCubic},$Opacity:2};
_CaptionTransitions["FADE*JDN|R"] = {$Duration:1200,x:-0.6,y:0.6,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$Linear,$Top:$Jease$.$OutCubic},$Opacity:2};

var options = {
    $FillMode: 2,                                       //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, 5 contain for large image, actual size for small image, default value is 0
    $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
    $Idle: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
    $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
    $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $Jease$.$OutQuad
    $SlideDuration: 800,                               //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
    //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
    //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
    $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
    $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
    $Align: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
    $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
    $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
    $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

    $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
        $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
        $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
        $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
        $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
    },

    $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                          //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                 //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
        $Rows: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
        $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $SpacingY: 8,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
    },

    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
    }
};

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (bodyWidth)
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

});

My question is...
What I need to replace or change in this code to change the slider transition effect by a FADE `{$Duration:3000,$Opacity:2}` ?

May be it could be a simple task, but I don't understand how to do it and I cant find a clear ans simple explanation in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing to define a variable

```
var jssor_SlideshowTransitions = [
        {$Duration:3000,$Opacity:2}
];
```

and then in options:

```
var options={
    // other options,
    $Transitions: jssor_SlideshowTransitions,
    // more options
```

check a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9xuhcmnz/7/)

Comment: Thank you Vickel, I m sorry but I tried inserting the variable and options, I tried looking the example, trying to make in the same way but it dont works. When I add the additional code you informed to me, the slider "freezes" and dont works. I dont have experience with Jssor and I feel it is not easy. May be I m inserting wrongly. Can you tell me where I need to insert this little code lines into the code I shown in my first question? THANK YOU anyway!

Comment: please check the fiddle I mentioned in my answer: https://jsfiddle.net/9xuhcmnz/7/

Comment: OK I will check tomorrow and after this I comment again. Hope I can understand better to give you a positive new :) . Thank you!